# FFPlay in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, exoplayer2.x, android-ffmpeg

My Android App, I want to show a preview of my FFmpeg command in exoplayer before the execution of the command.
I have checked the ffplay but how to use it in android there is no documentation or any library which works.

Comment: Not much to work with here, but I assume you tried to compile `ffplay` but did not have the required sdl2 dependency.

Comment: @llogan can you share some more detail about sdl2 dependency

Comment: You need to install whatever package provides `SDL.h` before compiling `ffplay`.

Comment: @MeetRathod did you find any solution?